# Changing the href of a link dynamiclly to only its hash value

Tags: jquery, url, hash, hyperlink, coda-slider

I have a main menu on top of my site, its on every page, it has some links to coda slider panels (featurepage#1, featurepage#2 etc) which work to take the user directly to that panel, when they are coming from a different page.

When Im actually on the FeaturePage, the links dont work, they only change the hash, without jumping to the relevant content.

As far as I can see, its because the links have the whole URL in them, rather than the needed #1, #2 etc.

So my question (and hope) is there a way of changing the HREF for those links just on that page, so featurepage#1 is turned into #1 and so on.

The problem as well its that its dynamic, I have no idea how many Hash values will be needed at any time, so I cant just simply replace them.

Would anyone have any ideas? Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this will remove everything before the # if one exists.  I would think though that this would be better done from the backend.  Don't have the page name in there to begin with.

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        var href=$(this).attr("href");
        if(href.indexOf("#")>-1){
            $(this).attr("href", href.substring(href.indexOf("#")))  
        }
    }); 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will be trying it in the morning as its late here now. Unfortunetly I dont have the page name, its actually for a WP theme, so the user can name the page whatever they want. Its a bit of a hacky solution I know, but im stuck! Thanks again for the help!